# Symfony 2: How to get route defaults by route name?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Is it possible to retrieve info about a certain route by its name, or get a list of all routes?

I need to be able to fetch the `_controller` value in `defaults` for any route, not only the current.

Is this possible and how?

P.S.: I found I could get the path to the routes YAML being used, but reparsing it seems unnecessary and heavy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am really good at answering my own questions..

To get routes use `getRouteCollection()` on the router (`$this -> get('router') -> getRouteCollection()` inside a controller), then you get RouteCollection instance on which you can `all()` or `get($name)`.

Comment: Keep in mind that `getRouteCollection` doesn't use any cached values as its intend is to rebuild the cache. So calling it is highly discouraged. It's not intended for use in production code and has a high performance impact (See: [Discussion about the YML routing loader not being cached at runtime](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7368#issuecomment-15146130)).

Answer (score 4):

As described in my comment above `Router::getRouteCollection` is really slow and not intended for use in production code.

So if you really need it fast, you have to hack your way through it. Be warned, *this is going to be hackish*:

---

**Directly accessing the dumped route data**

To speed up route matching, Symfony compiles all static routes into one big PHP class file. This file is generated by `Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\Dumper\PhpGeneratorDumper` and declares a `Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGenerator` that stores all route definitions in a private static called `$declaredRoutes`.

`$declaredRoutes` is an array of compiled route fields indexed by the route's name. Among others (see below) these fields also contain the route defaults.

In order to access `$declaredRoutes` we have to use a [\ReflectionProperty](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php).

So the actual code is:

```
// If you don't use a custom Router (e.g., a chained router) you normally
// get the Symfony router from the container using:
// $symfonyRouter = $container->get('router');
// After that, you need to get the UrlGenerator from it.
$generator = $symfonyRouter->getGenerator();

// Now read the dumped routes.
$reflectionProperty = new \ReflectionProperty($generator, 'declaredRoutes');
$reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
$dumpedRoutes = $reflectionProperty->getValue($generator);

// The defaults are at index #1 of the route array (see below).
$routeDefaults = $dumpedRoutes['my_route'][1];
```

---

**Fields of the route array**

The fields of each route are filled by the above mentioned `Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\Dumper\PhpGeneratorDumper` like this:

```
// [...]
$compiledRoute = $route->compile();

$properties = array();
$properties[] = $compiledRoute->getVariables();
$properties[] = $route->getDefaults();
$properties[] = $route->getRequirements();
$properties[] = $compiledRoute->getTokens();
$properties[] = $compiledRoute->getHostTokens();
$properties[] = $route->getSchemes();
// [...]
```

So to access its requirements you would use:

```
$routeRequirements = $dumpedRoutes['my_route'][2];
```

---

**Bottom line**

I've looked through the Symfony manual, the source code, forums, stackoverflow etc. but still wasn't able to find a better way of doing this.

It's brutal, ignores the API, and might break in future updates (although it hasn't changed in the most recent Symfony 4.1: [PhpGeneratorDumper on GitHub](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.1/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/Dumper/PhpGeneratorDumper.php)).

But it's rather short and fast enough to be used in production.

Comment: Just a note you can't get route options this way, apparently according to symfony devs Options are for compilation phase only.

Comment: @WiR3D ...but that doesn't stop you from reading the options from the `declaredRoutes` property. As I stated this is not API conform and may break in the future but nonetheless it's a working way to get the default options of a route. Keep in mind that the question wasn't about changing the options. That's not possible, because the routes already have been compiled. But reading them is possible.

Comment: yes you can read `declaredRoutes` but it doesn't cache all the route information, for example it caches data in `defaults` but it didn't cache data in `options`

Comment: @WiR3D Ah, now I understand what meant by your previous post. Yes, that's right. As can be seen in the excerpt above `$route->getOptions()` isn't stored in the `$properties` array.